# Inserting new random uuid() in two tables in every insert

Tags: mysql

I have created two tables which i want to insert similar data in.

```
 CREATE TABLE one(
  one_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (one_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

 CREATE TABLE two(
  two_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (two_id)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

every time in run insert.

To do that,i am using transactions

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET @name = uuid();

INSERT INTO one(one_id,name) VALUES (Null,@name);

INSERT INTO two(two_id, name) VALUES (Null, @name);

COMMIT;
```

This does not produce new values on new inserts.It however inserts the same data in the field name as i wanted.

How can i make this work?.

Comment: "name" must be the same in each tables or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a need to move to transactions in order to do that, just add an before insert trigger to the table .

Something like :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ONE_TABLE_TRIGG` BEFORE INSERT ON  `one` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
SET NEW.name= UUID( );
END ;
```

You can check if it's null before doing that. do this on both tables and you're good or add insert to the other table on 1 trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without much complexities by having several having several transaction statements in the same file

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET @name = uuid();

INSERT INTO one(one_id,name) VALUES (Null,@name);

INSERT INTO two(two_id, name) VALUES (Null, @name);

COMMIT;

START TRANSACTION;

SET @name = uuid();

INSERT INTO one(one_id,name) VALUES (Null,@name);

INSERT INTO two(two_id, name) VALUES (Null, @name);

COMMIT;
```

/*
Etc
*/